# Stored procedure not returning all records when passing multiple values to the parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, multiple-value

I know that this topic has been discussed many a times here. But I have spent 2 days and still couldn't figure out the issue with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a stored procedure that expects 6 parameters and I am passing multiple values for them. The stored procedure returns the correct records when single value is selected.

Please find the stored procedure code, and I am using an udf [`ufnsplit`] that is used to split passed values in tables

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1]
    @BUClass AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Office AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @writer AS NVARCHAR(MAX),        
    @From AS DATETIME,
    @To AS DATETIME,
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

   ;WITH UWS AS 
   (
       SELECT
           [Prefix],
           BusinessUnit,
           Office,
           Writer,
           FormName,
           Company
       FROM 
           A
       WHERE    
           BUClass IN (SELECT item FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@BUClass, ','))
           AND Office IN (SELECT item FROM [dbo].[ufnSplit](@Office, ','))
           AND Writer IN (SELECT item FROM [dbo].[ufnSplit](@writer, ','))
           AND Expiry_DT >= @From
           AND Expiry_DT <= @To
    ) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM UWS
END
```

The function I am using is

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnSplit]
    (@RepParam NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delim CHAR(1)= ',')
RETURNS @Values TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @chrind INT
    DECLARE @Piece NVARCHAR(100)

    SELECT @chrind = 1 

    WHILE @chrind > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @chrind = CHARINDEX(@Delim, @RepParam)

        IF @chrind  > 0
            SELECT @Piece = LEFT(@RepParam, @chrind - 1)
        ELSE
            SELECT @Piece = @RepParam

        INSERT INTO @Values(Item) VALUES(@Piece)

        SELECT @RepParam = RIGHT(@RepParam, LEN(@RepParam) - @chrind)

        IF LEN(@RepParam) = 0 
            BREAK
    END

    RETURN
END
```

When I pass multiple values, 0 records are returned, or the first value passed into the parameter. I am passing values like

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Test1]
                @Office = N'ATLANTA, 
                            BERKELEY HEIGHTS, 
                            BOSTON, 
                            CHICAGO, 
                            CLEVELAND',
                @BusinessClass = N'Commercial Management Solutions,
                                   HEALTHCARE, 
                                   PROGRAMS - PROFESSIONAL, 
                                   CANADA',
                @writer = N'Grant Duggar, 
                            Alyssa Gulich, 
                            Amanda Kelly,   
                            Daniel Chavenson, 
                            Deborah Wilieko, 
                            Derek Barbe'
                @From = N'1/1/2018',
                @To = N'4/1/2018',
```

I have ran a simple query against the database, just to check that there is data for these criteria. I get data back

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM A
WHERE BUclass IN (SELECT DISTINCT BUClass FROM A)
  AND Office IN (SELECT DISTINCT Producing_Office FROM A)
  AND UWName IN (SELECT DISTINCT UWName FROM A)
  AND Expiry_DT = '1/1/2018' 
  AND Expiry_DT <= '4/1/2018'
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? I have spent lots of hours on it but still no luck .

Thanks !

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: First, why don't you try deleting new lines in the parameters you're passing (instead of `ATLANTA,_NEWLINE_ BERKELEY HEIGHTS` write it like `ATLANTA,BERKELEY HEIGHTS,...` and let us know the outcome?

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! it worked. can you please tell me what is the difference between passing a new line and without new line ? how it worked ?

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you must do is get rid of the new lines in your parameters because:

```
@BusinessClass = N'Commercial Management Solutions,
                                   HEALTHCARE, 
                                   PROGRAMS - PROFESSIONAL, 
                                   CANADA'
```

is not the same as

```
@BusinessClass = N'Commercial Management Solutions,HEALTHCARE,PROGRAMS - PROFESSIONAL,CANADA'
```

and you're telling your function that the only delimiter is comma (`,`) which it isn't, it's comma **and** a new line for the first snippet of code which would essentially be `, + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`. This `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` actually means *new line*. In order to read up a bit more on the subject I'd direct you towards this [little article](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/01/sql-server-difference-between-line-feed-n-and-carriage-return-r-t-sql-new-line-char/). Explains the issue directly and this works both ways (when you're "searching" for something like you are or when you want to add new lines to a (n)varchar).